# Touch Xna : x:infity y:infinity

Tags: c#, xna

This is my code

```
            TouchCollection touch = TouchPanel.GetState();
            if (touch.Count >= 1)
            {
                TouchLocation prevLocation;
                bool prevAvailable = touch[0].TryGetPreviousLocation(out prevLocation);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("x:"+touch[0].Position.ToString()+"prev"+prevLocation.Position.ToString());

            }
```

but in output window i got " x:infinity , y:infinity " . It's not a true position .
any idea plsss Thanks :D

Comment: Which position is infinity? `prevLocation`? Maybe the reason is that you are not checking if `prevAvailable` is false.

Answer (score 0):

Tried your code and i didnt see in output "x:infinity , y:infinity". If `prevAvailable` is false (and its false when `touch.State == Pressed`) `prevLocation` initialized by default value Vector2(0,0). If `prevAvailable` is true (it is when`touch.State == Moved`) then it gets last touch location and work just fine. So there is not issues in this code.
Output sample

```
x:{X:216 Y:363}prev{X:0 Y:0} //state == pressed
x:{X:225 Y:347}prev{X:216 Y:363}
x:{X:244 Y:321}prev{X:225 Y:347}
x:{X:272 Y:293}prev{X:244 Y:321}
x:{X:272 Y:293}prev{X:272 Y:293}
x:{X:443 Y:210}prev{X:0 Y:0} //state == pressed
x:{X:443 Y:210}prev{X:443 Y:210}
x:{X:453 Y:195}prev{X:443 Y:210}
x:{X:471 Y:176}prev{X:453 Y:195}
x:{X:506 Y:145}prev{X:471 Y:176}
x:{X:506 Y:145}prev{X:506 Y:145}
```